# rails_admin javascript error when toggle add_filter menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, rails-admin

I found this html for **add_filter** menu:

```
<li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Add filter
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="filters" style="left:auto; right:0;">
  <li>
    <a data-field-label="Title" data-field-name="title" data-field-options="" data-field-type="string" data-field-value="" href="#">Title</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-field-label="Book type" data-field-name="book_type" data-field-options="" data-field-type="string" data-field-value="" href="#">Book type</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-field-label="Category" data-field-name="category" data-field-options="" data-field-type="belongs_to_association" data-field-value="" href="#">Category</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-field-label="Detail" data-field-name="detail" data-field-options="" data-field-type="text" data-field-value="" href="#">Detail</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

[image: Addfilter]

When I click on Add Filter the console logs:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'`

- When I create a new empty project and install rails_admin gem, it works.
- My project is using bootstrap for css and js.

Please give me some advice for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Sorry for noise, I has found out my problem
The gem twister-bootstrap-rails isn't compatible with rails_admin. Just remove this line in GEMFILE, then rake assets:clean, and finally run bundle again, the javascript worked.
My answer is found at [Github](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1202)